# The method 'configure' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseMessaging'. Can anyone retype my code correctly? Thanks

Tags: flutter, configure

1. Push Notification code.
   I don't understand how to implement the new method of implementing a notification in flutter using firebase

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class PushNotificationService
{
  final firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialize(context) async
  {
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm new to flutter dev and i'm currently working on a project

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using the old method. Here is the updated version. [Link for your references](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/)

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
  showNotification(notification);});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("onMessageOpenedApp: $message");});

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");});
```